# Как оптимизировать спавн и удаление большого количества 2d объектов в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Я создаю простые объекты через Instantiante и удаляю через 5 - 10 секунд с помощью Destroy. Мне кажется, что именно это является проблемой и этот код сильно уменьшает количество fps на слабых устройствах. Какие есть способы оптимизации такой системы?
Вот игра, если нужно - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.DaedStudio.InfinityCircle

Comment: вам может пригодиться пул объектов.  Когда создаете что то ,то вносите его в пул и если нужно удалить, то просто прячете. А если нужно создать заново, то смотрите в пуле, есть ли доступный элемент и просто снова показываете его, если же нету, то создаете.

Comment: `Instantiante` и `Destroy` это дорогие операции (не только в Unity). Пул который сразу спавнит `X` элементов и при необходимости расширяется не по одному, а сразу на `N` объектов и сокращается так-же.